# when import the solution it will overwrite the virtual connector data source

Tags: dataverse

I have a virtual table within a solution, the data is fomr sql database, when the test environment should be linked to the Sql Test Database, and the Dev Environment should be linked to sql Dev databse.

The problem is that each time when I implement the deloyment form Dev to Test environment, the virtual data souce - sql database also changed, it was overwritten to Dev Sql

Anyone have ideas about the ALM in dataverse virtual table?